# Vim c-remap common typos

Tags: vim

I frequently type `:E` (uppercase) instead of `:e` (lowercase) when I wish to open a file. Same goes for the mappings of `:w[a]` and `:q[a]`.

I thought I could fix that with the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
cnoremap E e
cnoremap W w
...
```

They work by transforming the E into e, but sadly it also makes it harder to open/save a file with an uppercase E, the latter gets transformed to lowercase on the fly. To get the uppercase letter I know have to ctrl-v <letter> in C-mode

Is there a better method to help me with my common typos?

Comment: As a side suggestion, I recommend giving a try to map space bar to `:` in normal mode (`:nnoremap <space> :`). It makes it much easier to enter command mode and you won't have the delay of releasing shift key. [Originally](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6553850/557306), `:` was a key by it's own which gave it a better flow in usage. And currently, I don't consider the standard space bar function very useful, so I remaped it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps you can create a customized command `W`, and forward the arguments to the real `w` command:

```
command! -nargs=* -bang W w<bang> <args>
```

Comment: Tested with E, this works but I lose tab completion of file name. I'll look more into it

Comment: @BlakBat You didn't mention the completion requirement in your question.   If you want it, add `-complete=file` in your command